# Django Model - How to set up ManytoMany, foreign key relation

Tags: django

I am trying to create a model,

where an individual can have multiple roles in multiple firms.

like a firm can assign an individual to Director and MD Roles, as well as Director role can be given to two separate individuals.

an individual can have multiple roles in multiple Firms like MD in FirmA and Directors & MD in FirmB.

I have three models, **Firm**, **Individual** and **FirmRole**.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I strongly suggest you read the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

Comment: not getting clear idea, because there is only for one foreign key and one manytomany, but i need it for three

Comment: Not very clear what you are looking for, you could t least present what you tried and what did not work. But you "just" need to define the linkes between each model, 2 by 2, and define related relationship

Comment: i update my model

Comment: just replace fk with m2m where you would like to have this relationship

Comment: I did that too, but django create three tables (firmindividualroles, firmindividualroles_firm and firmindividualroles_role) and relation between firm and role is not there

Comment: Yes, [it's a normal behavior](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) to have these technical tables, that you can also manage by your own. Please update your model definition with m2m relationships as you defined them

Comment: thanks, @Christophe, Really Appreciate it, I use a different approach, as I use choice for roles and FK for individuals and firms. Have to modify my view for unique value. If you have any idea about how to make all 3 values in a model then please share it. Thanks Again